# Google App Engine/Webapp2 redirect for HTTP HEAD requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using Google App Engine and webapp2's RedirectRoute method to handle the urls like this:

```
app  = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    RedirectRoute('/notes/', handler=notes, strict_slash=True, name="notes"),
    ...
    ])
```

This works as expected: requests for `/notes/` are handled by my handler and requests for `/notes` gets `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` redirecting to `/notes/`.

Exactly what I want.

But now I have added a `HEAD` handler. This works fine for `/notes/` but HEAD requests for `/notes` are getting `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` rather than what I was expecting: another `301 Moved Permanently`. It neither redirects nor makes it to my handler.

What am I missing? Is this expected behavior? How am I supposed to redirect HEAD requests?

**EDIT**

Based on Alex Martelli's idea below, this works, but I'm so surprised that there's not another way that I feel like I'm doing something wrong or at least the hard way.

Subclassing both `webapp2.RedirectHandler` and `webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute` works:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute

class myRedirectHandler(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
    def head(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(*args, **kwargs)

class myRedirectRoute(RedirectRoute):
    def _get_redirect_route(self, template=None, name=None):
        template = template or self.template
        name = name or self.name
        defaults = self.defaults.copy()
        defaults.update({
            '_uri': self._redirect,
            '_name': name,
            })
        new_route = webapp2.Route(template, myRedirectHandler,
                    defaults=defaults)
        return new_route
```

HEAD requests now redirect, but I'm not certain if it's worth it.

Comment: Perhaps this question will be helpful:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/99894

Comment: I appreciate that. I seems to suggest, however, that we should be able to send 301 redirects as a response to HEAD requests, which is what I would like to do here.

Comment: @MarkM, I agree it's a lot of work -- maybe put it in place for now and suggest the extension to the author of webapp2, it would be much easier to do by editing that code than "from outside" like you're correctly doing.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html , `RedirectRoute` has a `methods` named argument (defaults to `None`), like every other route as per [https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route.**init**](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route.__init__) .

Passing `methods=['head', 'get']` as part of the instantiation of `RedirectRoute` should thus be what you require.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Like it says in the link you posted: "A sequence of HTTP methods. If set, the route will only match if the request method is allowed." However, what it doesn't say in the docs, but does in the source is what happened if it's not set: "Sequence of allowed HTTP methods. If not set, all methods are allowed."

Either way, setting `methods=['HEAD', 'GET']` results identical behavior.

Comment: p.s. Looking through the source it seems like redirects end up getting handled by
 
`class RedirectHandler(RequestHandler):`

This class appears, strangely to only implement a `get()` method implying that webapp2 can only redirect HTTP GET requests. But, from my vantage point it's hard to tell if I'm correct about this.

Comment: Then `RedirectHandler` needs to be subclassed to implement a `def head(self, *a, **k): return self.get(*a, **k)`.  How to convince `RedirectRoute` to use your subclass may also require subclassing it, in turn.

Comment: Alex, that seems to have worked, but it makes me feel like I shouldn't be forwarding HEAD requests. See edit above.